# How can I get my 'click' event handler to reference these specific elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-dawn-452vo?file=/src/App.js) of a problem I've run into. I'm using React:

```
    <div className="1" onClick={onClickHandler}>
     <div className="2">
      <img className="3">
     </div>
    </div>
```

In scenarioA, `img` wasn't present & `onClickHandler`'s `e.target` referenced element `2`. I believe this is because:

1. '1' & '2' overlapped each other - when you clicked on one you clicked on the other.
2. Like `e.currentTarget`, `e.target` will reference the 'highest' element you click on that has a 'click' handler - with an exception: if the element has a descendant that is also clicked on when you click, it'll reference the lowest descendant.

**The problem:** in scenarioB, `img` has been added & now `e.target` refers to `img`. I need to refer to element `1` & `2` and intend to do this with the event handler staying on '1'.

**Solutions:**

1. Somehow, in `onClickHandler` get it to see '2'.
2. Refactor `img` to be like '2'. In my project, I think all this'd involve is making `img` have all the html attributes '2' has. However, I know having the attributes on '2' works - and even though I can't think of a way why this solution would break, I'm hesitant - especially if solution#1 works.

---

Comment: Just attach the listener to 2 and use .currentTarget which `always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached` per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).

Comment: Thanks @pilchard I've updated to the question to say one of the conditions is the event handler must stay on element '1'. I want to reference elements `1` & `2`.

Comment: is two always the first child? then `e.currentTarget.firstElementChild` or apply a ref or query 2.

Comment: How about using e.target.parentNode ? Possible ? @tonitone120

Answer (score 0):

**Summarizing the Question and Solution**

Below you can see two onClickHandler that logs out the event.target.

**Expected**: retrieve the parent node of the leaf nodes (children nodes without children nodes or innermost HTML element).

**Actual**: retrieved the leaf nodes.

**Fix**: change  `event.target` to `event.target.parentNode`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  function onClickHandler(event) {
    console.log(event.target); // THE FIX: change this to event.target.parentNode
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="one" onClick={onClickHandler}>
        <div className="two"></div>
      </div>

      <div className="one" onClick={onClickHandler}>
        <div className="two">
          <img className="three" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```